# How to target WorkManager to multiple clusters without hardcoding cluster name or specifying cluster names in property file

Tags: weblogic, wlst

i have a WLST script to setup WorkManager and target it to all the clusters in a weblogic domain. Issue is that i have hundred's of domains across multiple env's so cannot have multiple property files. Is there a way to script wlst to pull cluster details from domain and set them as target to created workmanager?

I tried to get cluster details using below,  but it is listing only one cluster where there are 3 clusters configured on the domain.

#

```
cd ('/Clusters')
Clusters = cmo.getClusters()
for clusters in Clusters:
        svr = clusters.getName()
print svr
```

#

Here is the wlst i am using:

#

```
import java.lang.Exception
# Connect to ADMIN
##################
userName=sys.argv[1]
userPW=sys.argv[2]
adminURL=sys.argv[3]
WL_DOMAIN=sys.argv[4]
exists = 'no';
connect(userName,userPW,adminURL)
edit()
startEdit()
cd ('/Clusters')
Clusters = cmo.getClusters()
for clusters in Clusters:
        svr = clusters.getName()
print svr
cd('/SelfTuning/' + domainName)
cmo.createWorkManager('workManager')
cd('/SelfTuning/' + domainName + '/WorkManagers/workManager')
set('Targets',jarray.array([ObjectName('com.bea:Name='+svr+',Type=Cluster')], ObjectName))
activate()
```

#

Above script targets the created work manager to only one cluster where the domain itself has 3 clusters. I would like to target WM to all the clusters in the domain without hard coding any cluster names. Please help !

Comment: You have a little bug in your script, you only display one cluster because the instruction "print svr" is not indented. So you are only printing the last cluster of your domain.

Comment: Hi Collin, thanks for the quick reply. Indenting "print svr" is now printing all 3 cluster names but targeting is not working for all 3 clusters. script is still targeting only last cluster. Please advise. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

it is an algorithmic issue. Your code is not correct.

```
connect(userName,userPW,adminURL)
edit()
startEdit()
cd('/SelfTuning/' + domainName)
cmo.createWorkManager('workManager')

cd ('/Clusters')
Clusters = cmo.getClusters()

cd('/SelfTuning/' + domainName + '/WorkManagers/workManager')
set('Targets',Clusters)
save()
activate()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Collin, works like a charm..!! Thanks for the explanation..

Comment: Hey Collin, just found out that script is not targeting the clusternames that have hyphen or underscore in it. Ex: "Cluster-1"  "Cluster-2"  Cluster_1" "Cluster_2". Please advise.

Comment: I am getting the following error: "WLSTException: Error occured while performing set : Error setting attribute Targets : argument type mismatch "

Comment: I have edited my answer to simplify a litlle bit the source code. Can you try it ? What is the webLogic version ?

Comment: Thanks Collin, it now works flawlessly for the Clusters that have either hyphen or underscore, what was i doing wrong earlier? Please let me know. Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Here you go: (just get rid of that svr variable)

```
cd ('/Clusters')
Clusters = cmo.getClusters()
for clusters in Clusters:
    print  clusters.getName()
```